# Regular expression containing Kubernetes cluster endpoint with IP or FQDN

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have a requirement in Angular/typescript to build a regex for a cluster endpoint that contains an IP or hostname (FQDN) in a URL
Something like this -

Example 1- 10.210.163.246/k8s/clusters/c-m-vftt4j5q

Example 2- fg380g9-32-vip3-ocs.sample.company.com/k8s/clusters/c-m-8vcjbtwh

(Slash at the end not allowed)

I have basically appended two different regular expressions
one for IP/FQDN:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$|^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

... and another for matching the rest of the URL
like `/k8s/clusters/c-m-vftt4j5q`

```
^\/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

My combined regular expression looks like this:

```
^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$|^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))[\/]{1}(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

But this matches with Example 2 but not Example 1

What do I need to modify here?

Comment: Actually the combined regular expression is not even satisfying an IP

Comment: Your first expression does not even appear to match `fg380g9-32-vip3-ocs.sample.company.com` to begin with? https://regex101.com/r/cnAjdc/1

Comment: What are the actual requirements for your FQDN check here? Does it have to match any specific pattern, or does it _just_ need to be a valid host name?

Comment: @CBroe It just needs to be a valid hostname

Comment: I separated this into two separate regular expressions - IP based endpoint

^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$

and FQDN based endpoint

^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$

https://regex101.com/ (ECMAScript)

Comment: I basically used a different regex for IP and different for FQDN and then appended the remaining regular expression for rest of the URL

Answer (score -1):

Modifying it to work the way you intend.
To that end I've slightly modified your last regex to work
for both sample cases.

```
/^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))\/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/zT32K6/1

RegexFormat :

```
^ 
(                                               # (1 start)
  (?:
    (?:
      25 [0-5] 
    | 2 [0-4] [0-9] 
    | [01]? [0-9] [0-9]? 
    )
    \. 
  ){3}
  (?:
    25 [0-5] 
  | 2 [0-4] [0-9] 
  | [01]? [0-9] [0-9]? 
  )
| (                                               # (2 start)
    (                                               # (3 start)
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
    | [a-zA-Z0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9-]* [a-zA-Z0-9] 
    )                                               # (3 end)
    \. 
  )+                                              # (2 end)
  ( [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9-]* [A-Za-z0-9] )          # (4)
)                                               # (1 end)
/
(                                               # (5 start)
  ( [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ )                               # (6)
  /
)+                                              # (5 end)
( [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ )                               # (7)
$
```

Comment: @appu_coder - If my post answers your question, it's customary to accept it as the answer. You can see the changes I've made showing where you went wrong. If you have a question related to this post please ask.